# AngularDart - How to style Component with global CSS in Google Chrome 35m (applyAuthorStyles is deprecated)

Tags: css, google-chrome, dart, angular-dart, shadow-dom

I am developing a big project using Angular Dart. Javascript will be generated from Dart using dart2js. The project is targeted for Google Chrome at the moment but in future, it should work in Firefox as well.

Everything was fine until Google Chrome 35m came out last week. All `Component` have broken stylesheet. It seems that `applyAuthorStyles` does not work in Google Chrome 35m.

I have spent lot of time to research and finally came up with the following solution:
Use `useShadowDom: false` when declaring a `Component`. It makes me refactor every existed `Component`s in my project:

- Remove `cssUrl`. I have to move stylesheet of each `Component` into one (or many) stylesheet file and import them in `index.html`
- Re-implement every `ShadowRootAware.onShadowRoot` since the method does not accept `ShadowRoot` as its argument
- Re-test (of course)

As you can see, there is so much extra work if I apply this solution.

I wonder if there is any better solutions than mine?

**EDIT**

I think I should explain my code structure to help everyone understand my issue better.

- I have many `Component` in my project. Each `Component` has 3 files: 1 CSS file (scoped), 1 HTML file and 1 dart file
- I have some global CSS files and import them at entry HTML page (index.html)
- In Chrome 35m, HTML in `Component` does not have style from global CSS even I set `applyAuthorStyles: true` (`applyAuthorStyles` is deprecated)

I just need a solution to style `Component` with global CSS (from a CSS Framework, for example), with minimal code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

If you don't use shadow DOM you can't have scoped CSS.

One alterantive is to keep shadow DOM and change the CSS you applied to your page to make it work with shadowDOM (add `/deep/` combinator for example).

Note: `applyAuthorStyles` was deprecated for several months already.

Since a while Angular.dart supports to create components without shadow DOM by adding the argument `useShadowDom: false` to the `@Component`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I know that `applyAuthorStyles` is deprecated but would you show me any ways to replace `applyAuthorStyle` with up-to-dated solution?

Comment: I don't know what to show you. You have to decide first which way you want to go. You can stick with the solution you proposed in your question or keep shadowDOM and change the CSS that doesn't work with shadowDOM. What information do you need?

Comment: I just need a solution that makes `Component` inherit all global CSS with minimal code changes.

Comment: Sorry, then I can only help when I have analyzed all your code.
Why did you need `applyAuthorStyles` anyway?

Comment: I have some global CSS files to define common style for whole website. In previous versions of Angular, I use `applyAuthorStyles` to make HTML nodes in `Component.shadowRoot` inherit all global CSSes.

Comment: If you created and maintain the CSS yourself it is easy. Its harder when you use CSS libraries like Bootstrap.
Can you add some of the CSS that causes you trouble with shadowDOM add to your question so we can discuss it or better create a new question because the topic is shifting away from the original question.

Comment: I will think a better way to describe my trouble. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You might take a look at this: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there's a good way to style everything in an Angular.dart project with a global css file, but I've found a work around that works for me.

My index file is a thin wrapper for my main component. Then I created a folder like: `lib/component/css/sass`. In `sass` I have created scss partials of all my css files (just rename it from something like `myCss.css` to `_myCss.scss`) and created a master scss file `lg-global.scss` that imports all those partials:

```
@import "pure-side-menu";
@import "pure-min";
@import "grids-responsive-min";

{... my css rules}
```

I've set up compass to compile my scss files to a single css file in the `css` folder, and now I can import that single file in my components like this:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'main-menu',
    templateUrl: 'main_menu.html',
    cssUrl: 'css/lg-global.css')
```

If I actually do want to have a specialized css file for a component, that's easy too. Just make a new scss file, and import whatever scss partials you want to.

It's a lot of extra work, but scss is a lot nicer anyway. My only real concern is whether it's going to be poor performance to use a massive css file in every component.

Comment: The browser takes the CSS file from the cache after firts load therefore doesn't impair performance.